# "An Ewt" to "A Newt"?

Tags: etymology, nouns, history, phonology, obscure-terms

What is it called when English speakers, over a long period of time, start adding the letter "n" to the beginning of a word by accident, due to use of the article "an"? For instance, I read somewhere that the word "newt" came from people mistaking "an ewt" for "a newt". I remember there is a term for it, but it's not coming to me.

Comment: A "gingrichism?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It’s called [***metanalysis*** or ***rebracketing***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebracketing), amongst many other things:

> **Rebracketing** (also known as **juncture loss, junctural metanalysis, false splitting, false separation, faulty separation, misdivision,** or **refactorization**) is a process in historical linguistics where a word originally derived from one source is broken down or bracketed into a different set of factors. It is a form of folk etymology, where the new factors may appear meaningful (e.g., *hamburger* taken to mean a burger with ham), or may seem to be the result of valid morphological processes.

There are many famous examples of this in English.  The rebracketing can go either way, making longer words:

- an ewte > a newt
- an eke name > a nickname
- an uncle > a nuncle

Or shorter ones:

- a napperon > an apron
- a nadder > an adder
- a nought > an ought

Even *orange* may be one such, although if so, this happened before it reached English.  Note the last part in the OED etymology for *orange* in English and others:

> **Etymology:** ME. *orenge*, *orange*, a. OFr. *orenge* (13th c.), *orange*, = Ital. *narancia* (Florio), now *arancia* (Venet. *naranza*, Milan. *naranz*), Sp.*naranja*, Pg. *laranja*, also med. Gr. νεράντζιον.
>
> The Sp. and Gr. are ad. Arabic *nāranj*, in Pers. *nārang*, *nāring*: cf. late Skr. *nāraṅga*, Hindī *nārangī*; also Pers. *nār* pomegranate.
>
> The native country of the orange appears to have been the northern frontier of India, where wild oranges are still found, and the name may have originated there.
>
> The loss of initial *n* in Fr., Eng.,and Ital. is usually ascribed to its absorption in the indef. article in *une narange*, *una narancia*.  Med.L. had also the forms *arangia*, *arantia* (Du Cange), whence *aurantia* by popular association with *aurum* gold, from the colour.  So perh. OFr. *orenge* for *arange*, after *or* gold.

They aren’t quite sure of that one, though.  But it does seem likely.

This process is of course still going on every day, and it may eventually lead to new words, or at least new spellings. Think of the catch-phrase *“Texas: it’s **a whole nother** country”*, where *another* is rebracketed as *a nother* thereby allowing the insertion of *whole* between the article and what follows.

This can occur at the phrase level, too. Linguist John McWhorter has an amusing example of *“Gladly, the cross-eyed bear”* being heard in the hymn line *“Gladly the cross I’d bear”*.  That’s essentially the same process that leads to hilarious (or confusing) [***eggcorns***](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/) appearing in print, like *“for all intensive purposes”* or *“when all is set and done”*.

Comment: I believe *[nuncle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nuncle)* actually goes the other way - "mine uncle" became "my nuncle".

Comment: Also, until this question, I'd never made the connection between an *eft* and a *newt* - but they're basically the same word.  Hmmm.

Comment: @MT_Head Yes, you’re right. I had it switched.

Comment: _Ought_ is also not really the same thing—at least not unless an original ‘ought’ was lost at some stage. ‘Nought’ is from _ne ā wiht_ ‘not ever a whit’, and the negating _ne_ was detachable originally; in the non-negated form, it was just _ā wiht_ > _ought_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Perhaps I misread then. Wikipedia says: “Middle English *a nought* ("a nothing") taken for *an ought*. Ultimately distinct from Old English *naught* ("nothing"), of complex and convergent etymology, from *na* ("not") and *wight* ("living thing, man"), but cf. *aught* ("anything", "worthy", etc.), itself ultimately from *aye* ("ever") and *wight* (SOED).”  An “everwight”?  How odd.

Comment: @MT_Head Yes, that’s right. OED says it started out as *efeta* in OE, but they’ve no idea where **that** one came from.  Pretty sure it wasn’t from *apheta* though. :)

Comment: @tchrist - It's well-known that amphibians are decadent: *[effete](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/effete)*, in other words.  Also that they're bad dancers: they have four left effete.

Comment: Regarding your Texas example: years ago, driving along California highway 49 through a small town in the Sierra Nevada (the "Mother Lode country", as it's known), I saw an establishment called the 'Nother Load Laundromat.

Comment: Good examples, but poor terminology. What happened what that a word boundary shifted. There really isn't a special name for that.

Comment: @JohnLawler I have some vague recollection from pertinent college courses long, long ago they said that the original was “re-analyzed” into a different pair of words, but that they didn’t really use any specific term for this phenomenon as seems to be happening now. I was surprised at the myriad alternate terms that the Wikipedia article gives. I’d have to dig into the professional literature to see whether those are actual terms of art or just random internet concoctions.

Comment: Who cares? Terminology is just pilpul; this kind of stuff happens all the time (_apron/nappy, orange/naranja, adder/Natter_) and there's nothing special about it. Different people analyze things in different ways, and fashions in writing change, that's all.